# How concatenating list of string if item contain part of string

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a `List<string>` as below:

```
List<string> source = new List<string>() {
  "Test;12345",
  "Test;6789",
  "Test;101112",

  "Demo;1", 
  "Demo;2", 
};
```

I need get this compressed into a new `List<string>`:

```
{ 
   "Test;12345;6789;101112",
   "Demo;1;2"
}
```

Regards,

Comment: try--> var result = string.Join(":", array);

Comment: Please explain. The word "Test" should appear only one time at the start of the resulting string. So you need to remove the following "Test" words from your inputs?

Comment: What is the expected result if we add `"Demo;1"` item into the `list`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko The expected result will be a list of string : Demo;1 and Test;12345;6789;101112

Comment: @Steve what i need is, when i have many items that contains the same word, i want to remove duplicated words and concatinate the rest of the strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your answer to my comment

> The expected result will be a list of string : Demo;1 and
>   Test;12345;6789;101112

You are looking for *Linq* `GroupBy` e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

List<string> source = new List<string>() {
  "Test;12345",
  "Test;6789",
  "Test;101112",

  "Demo;1", 
  "Demo;2", 
};

List<string> result = source
  .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {';'}, 2))
  .GroupBy(line => line[0], line => line[1])
  .Select(group => $"{group.Key};{string.Join(";", group)}") 
  .ToList();
```

Let's have a look:

```
Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Test;12345;6789;101112
Demo;1;2
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need, it works for me, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code,

```
var result = source.ToLookup(x => x.Split(";")[0], x=>x.Split(";")[1]).Select(x => string.Concat(x.Key,";",string.Join(";",x))).ToList();
```